# WebServiceContext is not injected using @Resource

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jetty, jax-ws

I know that has been asked before, but none of the solutions worked for me. Probably because they were mostly using EE compliant application servers, which is **NOT** my case.

I'm running my web service on jetty (through Eclipse) for development only. But even for deployment, I'll use Tomcat 7. So for either development or production, **I won't be using a JavaEE compliant server.**

- So is it still possible to inject `WebServiceContext` into my web
  services ?

I've tried the following but it didn't work

```
@WebService
@BindingType(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
public class IxProIntegration {
    // Tried this, didn't work
    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext wsContext;

    // After commenting the @Resource annotation on the wsContext field
    // And adding the annotation here, this still didn't work.
    @Resource
    @WebMethod(exclude = true)
    public void setContext(WebServiceContext context) {
        this.wsContext = context;
    }
```

- When someone kindly gives an answer, I would LOVE to know from where
  did he get that answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a dependency injection framework called Tapestry. Tapestry is managing the service instantiatiion. But the web service isn't managed by JAX-WS. That's why the context is always `null`. I [asked a new question related to the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548965/integrating-jax-ws-with-tapestry), in case someone needs an answer.