# Integrating JAX-WS with Tapestry

Tags: jax-ws, tapestry

I have experimented with [Derkoe's code](http://derkoe.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/integrating-metro-with-tapestry-2/) that integrates `JAX-WS` services with Tapestry's. Tapestry is a web and DI (i.e. Dependency Injection) framework.

The code works great but [I couldn't fully use all JAX-WS features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525723/webservicecontext-is-not-inject-using-resource).

Tapestry's IoC creates a proxy for my web services, and thus doesn't honor JAX-WS annotations.
And JAX-WS context listener, doesn't of course honor Tapestry's configuration for my service, so it won't perform any DI.

So I can either operate my Tapestry services, without JAX-WS full support, only web methods will be called,

Or

I can use JAX-WS full support, but none of the DI support.

So how can I integrate JAX-WS with Tapestry's IoC ? This is mainly a JAX-WS question.

- How can I extend\modify, how JAX-WS create services ?

As far as I have reached, I should replace [this class (InstanceResolver)](https://java.net/projects/jax-ws/sources/sources/content/branches/jaxws22/jaxws-ri/rt/src/com/sun/xml/ws/api/server/InstanceResolver.java?rev=12535). But how ? I can't find a **clear answer**.

I can't use any other framework. Only JAX-WS and Tapestry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it :)

In Derkoe's `ServiceInvoker` class. The method `start` is empty. Just put that line in it:

```
ResourceInjector.STANDALONE.inject(wsc, service);
```

I borrowed it from the `com.sun.xml.ws.server.SingletonResolver<T>` class.